# Конфликтующие расширения Metamask и Trust Wallet с объектом window.ethereum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, ethereum

Я создаю сервис для себя и хочу, чтобы он мог работать с расширениями браузера Metamask и Trust Wallet, а возможно, и другими в будущем. Однако я не могу найти информацию о том, как вызвать то, что мне нужно, когда установлены оба расширения.

Например, я хочу иметь кнопку для Metamask и кнопку для Trust Wallet. Нажатие каждой кнопки должно открывать необходимое окно подключения (но только одно расширение может быть подключено в данный момент).

Я наткнулся на web3-react, но он не работает с новыми версиями React. Я работаю с Next.js и еще не имею большого опыта работы с ним.

Я знаю, что это возможно реализовать. Это сделано на https://daomaker.com/. Возможно, кто-то имеет опыт в этом деле.

Если Metamask отключен, то должен вызываться Trust Wallet. Я пытался использовать window.ethereum и window.web3, но они оба кажутся открывающими только расширение Metamask для меня.